# Create empty URL object from scratch in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url

I want to manually construct URL from parts using the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object.

However, it's constructor requires a proper URL string to be passed to it, which doesn't allow to start from empty object and build it progressively.

1. Is there a way to overcome this limitation somehow?
2. What caused such design decision in the first place?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to use a `URL` object? Is it to extract the protocol, host etc?

Comment: I want to build proper URL string from scratch by specifying it's parts. This is a classic builder pattern scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have already figured out the workaround and there is no alternative other than passing the parts in or starting with a URL and mutating it.

I'll try to answer:

> What caused such design decision in the first place?

By far the most common use case for URLs was to create a URL from a URL string. Someone actually did end up [asking for the API you are describing in the URL spec](https://github.com/whatwg/url/issues/354) and discussion mostly stalled.

We [have an API in Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_format_urlobject) for constructing URLs from parts - but that creates a string one would still need to pass to the URL constructor.

So **this is likely not a bad idea** and it is **currently blocked on someone actually doing the work of adding that capability**.

Answer (score 5):

The only workaround I've found so far is to use minimal correct URL to initialize the object and then to override it's parts (namely protocol and host).

```js
const url = new URL('https://example.com');

url.protocol = 'http';
url.host = 'google.com';

console.log(url.toString()); // outputs: http://google.com/
```

However, it's still cumbersome for this use case.

Comment: This won't work for `origin` or `searchParams` as they are read only properties. They can't be overriden.

Comment: If you care about `searchParams` as well you could do this: https://github.com/whatwg/url/issues/354#issuecomment-751504831-permalink:~:text=Update%3A%20actually%20maybe%20this%20could%20work%3A

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to overcome this limitation somehow?

**Yes!** and I'm really suprissed hardly anyone is talking about it!

`thismessage:` was designed exactly for this purpose!

> The handling of relative and absolute URIs for matching between body parts have been merged into a single description, by specifying that relative URIs, which cannot be resolved otherwise, should be handled as if they had been given the URL "thismessage:/".
> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557.html#section-12

> When the methods above do not yield an absolute URI, a base URL of "thismessage:/" MUST be employed. This base URL has been defined for the sole purpose of resolving relative references within a multipart/related structure when no other base URI is specified.
> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557.html#section-5

The concept is that *first* argument to the URL constructor is the *path* either absolute or relative and the *second* argument is the base URI to associate this to. We typically think of the base as something like `https://example.com/` but that is not necessary especially when the URL we are building does not have any need for such a base.

```js
let url = new URL('some/path/we/care/about', 'thismessage:/');
url.searchParams.set('foo', 'bar');

// 12 being the length of 'thismessage:'
let resultWithoutProtocol = url.href.substring(12);

document.querySelector('output').value = resultWithoutProtocol;
```

```html
<code><output></output></code>
```